# add data to json (php)

Tags: php, json

can someone please help me to add data to following json.

```
$temp='{
  "custId": 123,
  "data": [
    {
      "code": "abc1"
    },
    {
      "code": "abc2"
    }
  ],
  "id": 102
}';
```

data to be added

```
$data1='{
      "code": "abc3"
    }';
```

Desired result

```
$temp='{
  "custId": 123,
  "data": [
    {
      "code": "abc1"
    },
    {
      "code": "abc2"
    },
    {
      "code": "abc3"
    }
  ],
  "id": 10
}';
```

I can append data to $temp, but can someone please help to add data to specific position with php. Thank you in advance. (I've tried json_decode($temp, true) and then finding the location where data1 is to be added but failed).

Answer (score 3):

You can convert your data to a normal PHP array:

```
$array = json_decode($temp, true);
```

then just add or change anything you want:

```
$array["data"][] = array(["code"] => "abc3");
```

and re-encode to json:

```
$temp = json_encode($array);// encode to json
```

http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php

Comment: Changed to add the changed stuff as a child to the data node as requested.

Comment: Fix: `$temp = json_encode($array);` and not `$temp ? json_encode($array);`.

Comment: Don't be angry. Make a tea :P

Comment: Wasnt angry. No worries here *sip* ;)

Answer (score 1):

first, you need to convert the JSON into PHP array like this:

```
$array = json_decode($temp, true);
```

Then, it's as simple as:

```
$array['data']['code'] = 'abc3';
```

If the string that you want to add is still a JSON, you have to convert that one in an array as well so:

```
$arr_to_add = json_decode($data1, true);
$array['data'][] = $arr_to_add;
```

In the end, of course, encode again like this:

```
$final_json = json_encode($array);
```

Hope this helps! :D

Comment: $array['data'] is going to be overridden on your code. It should be append values with []...?

Answer (score 0):

1. First you need to decode the json with `json_decode`. This returns a PHP variable.
2. Add desired values.
3. Use `json_encode` to get the json with new values. Returns a string containing the JSON.

Comment: Worth noting that the 2nd parameter of json_decode determines whether the JSON string will be decoded to a multi-dimensional array or a standard class object.

Answer (score 0):

you can try this:

```
<?php
$temp='{
  "custId": 123,
  "data": [
    {
      "code": "abc1"
    },
    {
      "code": "abc2"
    }
  ],
  "id": 102
}';
$data1='{
      "code": "abc3"
    }';
$jarr=json_decode($temp,true);
$appArr=json_decode($data1,true);
$desire=array_merge($jarr,$appArr);
//print_r($desire);
echo json_encode($desire);
```